# How to fork form Geth light client to Ganache CLI?

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache, light-clients, ganache-cli

I am currently forking the Ethereum mainnet into Ganache CLI using Infura (command: `ganache --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/my_project_id`) However, I want to use my own Geth light client with Ganache instead of using Infura. Is there any way that is possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need an archive node to fork, so your light Geth client won't work as it's not keeping the network states.

What exactly are trying to achieve?